# How to detect leading numberings in titles with a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to detect if a sequence of text begins with a numbering, eg `I)`, `IV.`, `a)`, `C/`, `C.` `C -`, `C-` etc with a regex. 
I tried the following regex :

```
m = re.search(r'^(IX?{\s|-|-\s|,|,\s|\)|\)\s|.|.\s}|IV?{\s|-\s|-|\)|\)\s|.\s|.}|VI{0,3}?{\s|-|-\s|\)|\)\s|.|.\s})', "II - Informations supplementaires")
m.group(0)
>> 'I'
m.group(1)
>> 'I'
```

It only gives me 'I' as a result, I don't have "II", "II -", which are expected .... What is my error in the pattern ^^ ?

Comment: Your pattern just does not match `II`, why do you say it is expected?

Comment: even with `m = re.search(r'^(IX?{\s|-|-\s|,|,\s|\)|\)\s|.|.\s}|IV?{\s|-\s|-|\)|\)\s|.\s|.}|VI{0,3}?{\s|-|-\s|\)|\)\s|.|.\s}|I{1,3})', "II - Informations supplementaires")` , "II" is not detected

Comment: What are you trying to match? Your regex is really weird man... I don't think it's even close to what you want. Post a bunch of sample strings. Also, do you want `II` as output or `II - `?

Comment: I want both. I think this pattern is more efficient `"^(IX|IV|VI{0,3}|I{1,3})(\s|-|-\s|,|,\s|\)|\)\s|.|.\s)"`

Comment: With `.` are you trying to match `.` literally? Also, it would **really** help if you posted multiple sample strings.

Comment: Which range of Roman numerals are you trying to match?